# Find the expected number of of questions

Tags: probability, expected-value

I was reading [Introduction to Probability, 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/188652923X) and the following problem appears on page 123:

> A prize is randomly placed in one of ten boxes, numbered from 1 to 10.
>
> You search for the prize by asking yes-no questions.
>
> Find the expected number of questions until you are sure about the
> location of the prize, under each of the following strategies:
>
> 1. An enumeration strategy: you ask questions of the form "is it in box `k`?".
> 2. (The second strategy omitted because it's not relevant to my question).

The answer in the book is $5.5$ which presumes that we need to ask 10 questions sometimes, but that's not true, we only need 9 questions at most since after asking 9 questions, either we find the box in one of the first 9 questions or not and then the prize is in the remaining box which makes the expected value equal to $5.4$.

Am I wrong, or either the solution of the book is wrong, or the question itself is not clear?

Comment: Your reasoning makes sense; the solution does not seem to match the description of the problem. It might be that the author is assuming that once you are sure which box to pick, you need to "spend" a question to win the prize, but this isn't clear from the problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book answer is incorrect.

The probability that you are sure after $1$ question is $0.1$

The probability that you are sure after precisely $2$ questions is $0.1$

The probability that you are sure after precisely $3$ questions is $0.1$

and so on until the end when

The probability that you are sure after precisely $9$ questions is $0.2$

The calculation then gives $5.4$ as you say.